# update_post_meta based on acf repeater field

Tags: custom-field

I'm trying to update post meta in an acf repeater fields have value using this function, but it's not working:

```
function save_photos_meta_data( $post_id ) {
    if( get_field('photos') ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'has_images', 'yes' );
    } else {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'has_images', 'no' );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_photos_meta_data' );
```

Where `photos` is the name of the acf field.

Comment: I'm setting an integer value not Boolean.

Comment: Sorry, misread the code.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the ACF `Field_XXXXXXX` label that your repeater field is assigned and can be found by issuing the following query,

> SELECT pm.meta_key FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta pm JOIN
>   ".$wpdb->prefix."posts po ON po.ID = pm.post_id WHERE pm.meta_value
>   LIKE '%{The repeater field name}%' AND po.post_title='{The Field Group
>   Name}'

You can use `wpdb->get_results()[0]['meta_key']`, to get the value of `pm.meta_key`.

Replace `{The Field Group Name}` with the Field Group name you assigned to your ACF fields,

Replace `{The repeater field name}` with the repeater field name (not the sub fields).

The `acf_repeater` field is looking for an array,

Given photos is you acf repeater field name, you did not specify your sub field name, so will use image as the sub field name,

```
$photos = array (array('image url'));

foreach ($photos as $key => $value) {

    update_metadata('post', 'photos_'.$key.'_image', $value);
    update_metadata('post', '_photos_'.$key.'_image', '_photos'.$key.'_image');

}
```

Now you have to update the acf repeater field,

```
update_metadata('post', $post_id, 'photos', count($photos));
update_metadata('post', $post_id, '_photos', $field_key);
```

where `$photos` is the array of photos, and `$field_key` is the `meta_key` obtained from the SQL query above.

This link is good explanation of the repeater field names in the meta table,
https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/adding-rows-into-a-repeater-field-programatically/

Comment: Function to update an ACF repeater field,

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Function: update_acf_repeater_field
 * Parameters:  $meta_type = post|user|comment
 *              $field_group_name = the name of ACF Field Group
 *              $repeater_field_name = the repeater field name 
 *              $subfields = a multidimensional array with the array keys matching the
 *                      the sub field names, e.g., array(array('subfield_name'=>'value','subfield_name'=>'value'))
 *              $post_id = the post id, user id or comment id 
 *
 * Developer: Patrick Ingle (https://github.com/patrickingle)
 *
 * Problem Resolved: Adding an ACF repeater field to a new post, comment or user. 
 *
 */
 function update_acf_repeater_field($meta_type,$field_group_name,$repeater_field_name,$subfields=array(),$post_id) {
global $wpdb;

foreach($subfields as $key => $subfield) {
    foreach ($subfield as $subkey => $value) {
        update_metadata($meta_type, $post_id, $repeater_field_name.'_'.$key.'_'.$subkey, $value);
        update_metadata($meta_type, $post_id, '_'.$repeater_field_name.'_'.$key.'_'.$subkey, $repeater_field_name.'_'.$key.'_'.$subkey);
    }
}
$sql = "SELECT pm.meta_key FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta pm JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."posts po ON po.ID = pm.post_id WHERE pm.meta_value LIKE '%$repeater_field_name%' AND po.post_title='$field_group_name'";
$field_key = $wpdb->get_results($sql,ARRAY_A)[0]['meta_key'];
update_metadata($meta_type, $post_id, $repeater_field_name, count($subfields));
update_metadata($meta_type, $post_id, '_'.$repeater_field_name, $field_key);
}
```